# Change wordpress loop depending on chosen term

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've create a page template page-products.php which displays all the products (custom post type "product"). You can see the page on this url: http://axces-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/producten/

On the left side of the page you have to filter. These are the taxonomy terms for the custom post type "product".

```
<?php
  $args = array('hide_empty' => false, 'orderby' => 'term_group', 'parent' => false);
  $terms = get_terms('product_categorie', $args);
  $hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy('product_categorie');
   echo '<ul class="filter">';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
     echo '<li class="parent"><strong class="parent__item">'.$term->name.'</strong>';
     if (array_key_exists($term->term_id, $hierarchy)) {
       echo '<ul class="childs">';
         foreach ($hierarchy[$term->term_id] as $v) {
           $child = get_term($v);
           echo '<li class="child" data-filter="'.$child->slug.'">'.$child->name.'</li>';
         }
      echo '</ul>';
     }
    echo '</li>';
   }
  echo '</ul>';
?>
```

All the products are shown with this code:

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'product'); ?>
   <?php $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
    <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
       <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content-product' ); ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
     <h1>
        <?php _e('Geen producten gevonden','axces-theme'); ?>
     </h1>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

But how am I able to change the product query depending on the clicked child term? So if I click on the term "Wandlezers" for example, I want to show only the products with the term "Wandlezers".

Answer (score 0):

Add a term link in your code like

```
<?php
      $args = array('hide_empty' => false, 'orderby' => 'term_group', 'parent' => false);
          $terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);
          $hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy('product_cat');
           echo '<ul class="filter">';
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
             echo '<li class="parent"><strong class="parent__item">'.$term->name.'</strong>';
             if (array_key_exists($term->term_id, $hierarchy)) {
               echo '<ul class="childs">';
                 foreach ($hierarchy[$term->term_id] as $v) {
                   $child = get_term($v);
                   echo '<li class="child" data-filter="'.$child->slug.'"><a href="?product_cat=' . $term->term_id. '">'.$child->name.'</a></li>';
                 }
              echo '</ul>';
             }
            echo '</li>';
           }
          echo '</ul>';
        ?>
```

Then change your loop query args like this

```
<?php
       $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'any'
        );

        if ( ! empty( $_GET['product_cat'] ) ) {
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'id',
                    'terms'    => $_GET['product_cat'],
                ),
            );
        }
        ?>
       <?php $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
        <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
           <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content-product' ); ?>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
         <h1>
            <?php _e('Geen producten gevonden','axces-theme'); ?>
         </h1>
       <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you sir! I've changed your code a little bit $term->slug and in the arguments 'field' => 'slug'. This way the URL will be: http://axces-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/producten/?product_categorie=waterkoker

But can I make the url like this: http://axces-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/producten/waterkoker ? So that the parameter (?product_categorie=) isn't visible in the url.

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to register custom rewrites and query vars. You can check this tutorial https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/building-customized-urls-wordpress/ and also can check some example code https://gist.github.com/carlodaniele/1ca4110fa06902123349a0651d454057